# cannot catch SQLAlchemy IntegrityError

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, sqlalchemy

Try as I might, I can't seem to catch the sqlalchemy IntegrityError correctly:

```
from sqlalchemy import exc

try:
    insert_record()
except exc.IntegrityError, exc:
    print exc # this is never called
    handle_elegantly() # this is never called
```

As what one might expect:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) insert or update on table "my_table" 
                violates foreign key constraint "my_table_some_column_fkey"
```

I've tried to explicitly:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
```

**UPDATE:**

I found something that seems to fit what's happening here, where Integrity Error isn't thrown until the session is flushed to the db, and after the `try`/`except`blocks have been executed: [Trying to catch integrity error with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313935/trying-to-catch-integrity-error-with-sqlalchemy)

However, adding `session.flush()` in the `try` block yields an `InvalidRequestError`:

```
ERROR:root:This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous 
           exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, 
           first issue Session.rollback(). 
           Original exception was: (IntegrityError)
```

Comment: Are you 100% this is where it's happening?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Also, does changing `IntegrityError` to `DatabaseError` help? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe `DatabaseError` doesn't seem to help, and I'm using Postgres.

Comment: @MartinKonecny Yep, I'm pretty sure. Print statements abound. There's something I'm missing here, but what? Maybe in the way the transaction is handled in the session, where IntegrityError isn't thrown until the session is flushed to the db, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313935/trying-to-catch-integrity-error-with-sqlalchemy

Comment: Where are you getting the message `"ERROR:root:This Session's...`. Seems to me the `print exc` is generating that message?

Comment: @MartinKonecny unfortunately, it's not the print statement (that would seem easier to troubleshoot), but through my server logs.

Comment: If you're using `pymysql` driver you might be able to catch `IntegrityError` from `pymysql.err`

Answer (score 69):

I have the same need in my Flask application, I handle it like below and it works:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import exc

db = SQLAlchemy(Flask(__name__))

try:
     db.session.add(resource)
     return db.session.commit()
except exc.IntegrityError:
     db.session.rollback()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use `exc.IntegrityError` without importing it from sqlalchemy first

Comment: What does `db.session.rollback()` do?

Answer (score 39):

As soon as the `IntegrityError` is raised, regardless of whether or not you've caught the error, the session you were working in is invalidated.  As the second error message is instructing you, `To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback().`, to continue using the session you'll need to issue a `session.rollback()`

I cannot say for sure, but I am guessing you or your web framework is attempting to continue using the session which raised the IntegrityError in some way.  I recommend you issue a `session.rollback()` either after you catch the exception or in your `handle_elegantly` function.

If you run the below you'll see what I mean:

```
from sqlalchemy import types
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    name = Column(types.String, primary_key=True)


def handle_elegantly(name):
    session = DBSession()
    session.add(User(name=name))
    session.flush()
    print 'Exception elegantly handled!!\n'


def pretend_view(request):
    """Pretend view in a Pyramid application using pyramid_tm"""
    session = DBSession()
    user = User()
    print '\n-------Here we rollback before continuing -------'
    try:
        session.add(user)
        session.flush()
    except exc.IntegrityError:
        session.rollback()
        handle_elegantly('This will run fine')

    print '\n------- Here we do not, and this will error -------'
    try:
        session.add(user)
        session.flush()
    except exc.IntegrityError:
        handle_elegantly('Exception will be raised')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    global DBSession
    DBSession = scoped_session(
        sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Base.metadata.create_all()
    pretend_view("dummy request")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `session.rollback()` after you catch an error:

```
try:
    session.flush()
except IntegrityError:
    session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same as the answers above, I want just to add an extra piece of code if you want to display some dynamic error on `except` to return it as a `JsonResponse` or whatever.

**Note**: outputting this type of error is not good in terms of security.

```
from sqlalchemy import exc


try:
     db.session.add(resource)
     return db.session.commit()
except exc.IntegrityError as e:
     err_msg = str(e.orig).split(':')[-1].replace('\n', '').strip()
     print(err_mg)
     return err_mg
```

**`exc.IntegrityError`** has a key called `orig` containing this message:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ix_table_column"
DETAIL:  Key (column)=(some_data) already exists.
```

This message has the type of `<class 'driver.errors.UniqueViolation'>` and not `str`, so we should convert it to `str` then with some simple string manipulation we got only the exact error, which is in this case:

```
Key (column)=(some_data) already exists.
```

Answer (score -4):

```
SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = False
```