# Unable to catch SQLAlchemy IntegrityError

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

If I try to commit a record to my database and it already exists then I want to use a try/except block to handle it:

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

try:
    session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    # do something else
```

However, I can't seem to catch the error. Here's a typical error that occurs on `session.commit()`:

```
Exception has occurred: IntegrityError
(mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '88306-1' for key 'match_feat.idx_match_feat__composite'
```

I wondered if I was trying to catch the wrong error so I tried using:

```
from mysql.connector.errors import IntegrityError
```

But I get the same error message.

The answers to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24522290/11277108) focus on adding `session.rollback()` to the `except:` block however this doesn't help me (or the OP?) as I'm getting the error in the `try:` block and so the `except:` block isn't ever triggered.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/QF09P7j5) works fine for me.

Comment: Hey Gord. Thanks. Weirdly that code works fine for me too. Not quite sure where I go from here - will do some more investigating.

Comment: this  seems to be present for me, because the i was bundling session.commit() 
so i have a record add that will throw that error but handeled with `pass` but when put into an other transaction, the exception will be remembered by the parent transaction, and once you try to commit the parent session tx it will rollback telling you that you have an issue

Answer (score 1):

Worked this out. The answers to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24522290/11277108) were correct. A `rollback()` is needed at the start of the `except` block. I'm not sure on the exact mechanics but the error was being caught on the first iteration of the code however if the transaction wasn't then rolled back then the second time through the error occurred in the `try` block and wasn't caught. This solved the issue:

```
try:
    session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    session.rollback()
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the [pass statement](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) was used in the `except` block to tell Python to do nothing, for example:

```py
try:
    session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    pass
```

As the example in the question would result in an `IndentationError` being raised.

Based on your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65477104/3892354), it seems that the `IntegrityError` is being raised elsewhere in the code and not by `session.commit()` inside the `try` block. I suggest reviewing the stack trace generated when the exception is raised to find out where in your code this exception is being raised. [The Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) can also be used to step through the code line-by-line.